# Replacing words in loop in python

Tags: python, loops, cpu-word

what's wrong with this code : I am trying to run this code in a loop and with every loop it take two arguments but it does not works, it's runs only two time then printing constantly unnecessary things.

Code:

```
words= "this is my computer and my computer is super computer"
wordlist = words.split(" ")
changed_wordlist=[]

while (True):
    
    replace = input("replace this: ")
    with_this = input("with this: ")
    for word in wordlist:
        
        if word == replace:
           replacedword = word.replace(replace, with_this)
           print(replacedword,end=" ") 
           changed_wordlist.append(replacedword) 
        
        elif word!= replace:
            print(word,end=" ")
            changed_wordlist.append(word)
    wordlist = changed_wordlist
```

Comment: What were you expecting it to print? What does it actually print?

Comment: question is solved by Sherlock Bourne . thanks for asking me.

Comment: if `word == replace` then you can simply `replacedword = with_this`

Comment: you can use shorter `else:` instead of `elif word!= replace:`

Answer (score 0):

I created an example that would change the words from the list, and then print its content after the change, both if the word was found or not. Try this:

```
words = "this is my computer and my computer is super computer"
wordlist = words.split(" ")

while (True):
    replace = input("replace this: ")
    with_this = input("with this: ")

    # Iterate over the list, looking for the word
    # to replace
    for i in range(len(wordlist)):
        # If we find the word, we replace it
        if wordlist[i] == replace:
            wordlist[i] = with_this
        
    print("The list is now: " + str(wordlist))
```